# Converting angular2-query-builder query to logical expression

Tags: java, angular, jquery-query-builder

I use [angular2-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder) in my project. Besides, the back-end project using Java, Spring boot and Rulebook as a rule engine in order to fire rules which are generated by angular2-query-builder. So I need to make a logical expression from the output of angular2-query-builder.

This is a type-script object generated by query-builder.

```
  query = {
    condition: 'and',
    rules: [
      {field: 'age', operator: '<=', value: '16'},
      {field: 'gender', operator: '=', value: 'm'}
    ]
  };
```

The mapped model class which I've made in the back-end :

```
RuleSet {
    String field;
    String value;
    String operator;
    String entity;
    String condition;
    RuleSet[] rules;
//...getters and setters}
```

I need to get `(age <= 16) && (gender = 'm')` from the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making a recursive method in order to traverse the rules

```
private void decode(RuleSet[] rules, List<String> expressions, String condition) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            RuleSet item = rules[i];
            if (item.rules == null) {
                expressions.add(merge("(", item.field, item.operator, item.value, ")"));
                if (i != rules.length - 1) {
                    expressions.add(condition);
                }
            } else {
                condition = item.getCondition();
                expressions.add("(");
                decode(item.rules, expressions, condition);
                expressions.add(")");
            }
        }
    }
public String merge(String... strings) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String item : strings) {
        if (item != null) {
            result.append(item);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

then call it like this:

```
List<String> expressions = new ArrayList<>();
decode(querySchema.ruleSet.rules, expressions, querySchema.ruleSet.condition);
```

by adding all items of expressions into a string object. The logical expression will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Taking reference from ramin,typeScript implementation of the same

First define the model as :

```
export class RuleSet {
    field?  : string;
    value? : string | string[] | number;
    operator? : string;
    entity ?: string;
    condition ?: string;
    rules ?: RuleSet[];
}
```

Then define decode functions :

```
  //params : [{field: 'age', operator: '<=', value: '16'},{field: 'gender', operator: 
  //'=', value: 'm'}],'and'
  decodeQuery(rules : RuleSet[], condition : string) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        var item :RuleSet = rules[i];
        if (item.rules == null) {
            this.expression = this.expression + this.mergeString("(", item.field, item.operator, item.value, ")");
            if (i != rules.length - 1) {
                this.expression = this.expression + " " + condition + " ";
            }
        } else {
            condition = item.condition;
            this.expression = this.expression + "(";
            this.decodeQuery(item.rules, condition);
            this.expression = this.expression + ")";
        }
    }
  }

  mergeString(bracket1,field,operator,value,bracket2) {
    var mergedString = bracket1 + " " + field + " " + operator + " " + value + " " + bracket2 ;
    return mergedString;
  }
```

calling it be like :

```
expression : string = "";
this.decodeQuery(query.rules,query.condition);
```

Resultant output be like :

```
(age <= 16) && (gender = 'm')
```